# Link to specific line in javascript source?

Tags: github, hyperlink

I have javascript source code served at `http://www.example.com/static/script.js`. I'm writing documentation and rather than including the code of certain functions I want to refer to, I'd just like to link to the source- but I would like to link to the specific line of the Function in the source document.

Is this possible, to create a link to a text document at a specific line without using html anchors or javascript `window.scrollTo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never found a way to link to javascript source, but easy to do with GitHub - Just add `"#L" + lineNo` to the url. For instance: https://github.com/ArbolEric/RaphaGraph/blob/master/src.js#L210

Highlights and jumps to line.